# ufunc.at for cases where target indices are unique (buffered call possible then)

Tags: python, numpy

I use `ufunc.at` similar as a sparse matrix multiplication or better, as a flow in a graph. `c[:, 0]` denotes the target index where each element denoted by the source index `c[:, 1]` will be summed up

```
c = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1]) # sum up 1 and 2 into 0, and 1 into 1
src = ... # source vector
targ = ... # target vector, not necessarily 0 in the beginning
np.add.at(targ, c[:, 0], src[c[:, 1]]) # sum up into bins
```

One could similarly write:

```
targ[c[:, 0]] += src[c[:, 1]]
```

That approach will only work if all target indices c[:, 0] are unique, else there will be sort of race conditions. I also expect, that it is a bit faster because it does not need to care about accumulation internally, but can just do an 'one shot' addition, what is way more efficient when it comes to vectorization. Numpy calls this buffered/unbuffered operation.

**Is there a similar syntax for the buffered version with unique target indices?** (Basically just for convenience and more consistently looking code.)

Comment: There are only 5 `ufunc` methods, and none of the others have this syntax.

Comment: In small time tests, the `np.add.at` and the `+=` approaches take the same time.  Worrying about a time penalty for the unbuffered approach might be premature.